# How to calculate sum from user input inside while loop

Tags: java, oop

I got two classes, this one and other called DailyExpenses that's full of getters and setters + constructors etc..

My problem is that I want to get the sum value of all daily expenses user inputs inside the while loop and print the sum after the program is closed, and I don't know how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DailyExpensesMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ArrayList<DailyExpenses> expenses = new ArrayList<DailyExpenses>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean isRunning = true;       
        
        System.out.println("Enter the date for which you want to record the expenses : ");
        String date = sc.nextLine();

        while(isRunning) {          
            System.out.println("Enter category: (quit to exit)");  
            String category = sc.nextLine();
            if(category.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {   
                 break;
            }

            System.out.println("Enter price: ");
            double price = sc.nextDouble(); 
         
            sc.nextLine();              
                                    
            System.out.println("Enter details: ");
            String detail = sc.nextLine();
             
            DailyExpenses newExpense = new DailyExpenses(date, category, price, detail);    
            expenses.add(newExpense);                   
        }
            
        sc.close();
        for(DailyExpenses u: newExpense) {      
            System.out.println("Date: " + u.getDate() + " Category: " + u.getExpenseCategory() + " Price: " + u.getExpensePrice() + 
                " Detail: " + u.getExpenseDetail());
        }       
    }
}
```

I still clueless on the situation